# USERELATIONSHIP in CALCULATE function returning wrong results

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

I am new to DAX and Power Pivot, I apologize in advance if there is a similar thread I did not see. I am using Excel 2016, I need to use USERELATIONSHIP in the CALCULATE function to use an inactive relationship in the data model (I need it for a slicer).

I am using this formula `=CALCULATE([Count of Fiscal Week Identified],USERELATIONSHIP(Table[Fiscal Week Identified],Week[Week]))` to create a calculated field I need to add to a pivot table.

I just need Excel to generate the pivot table on the left in the screenshot using a calculated field inserted in values, and the field 'week' in rows (having an inactive relationship in the data model). When I tried using the formula above, I get the table on the right which is completely different from the table on the left, and I cannot figure out why... I need this to include the pivot table in a slicer. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Hello again,



After digging into it, I found out the USERELATIONSHIP function is not working... The relationship does exist (see the data model), I set them both to "inactive". Does anyone know why the function is not working?



This is the formula I am using to calculate the measure: ```= CALCULATE(COUNT(DAS_Pipe[Fiscal Week Identified]),USERELATIONSHIP(DAS_Pipe[Fiscal Week Won],Week[Week]))```

Comment: Can you please share the Excel file with just some randomized data which mimics the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that even though you are creating column using USERELATIONSHIP, the relationship isn't active when this column is evaluated in Pivot Table. So you need to use a Measure. Is the below the expected result?

[image]

If yes, then create a measure like this:
[image]